# Selecting Month and year from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If in a column I have a timestamp ie. 2010-04-01 10:40:20  How can I use SQL to select everything from October 2011?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE col1 >= '2011-10-01' AND col1 < '2011-11-01'
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTHNAME(filed_date) = 'October' AND YEAR(field_date)='2011'
```

Comment: Why `MONTHNAME` I'd go with `MONTH`, ie `WHERE MONTH(filed_date) = 10 ...`, should be tiny bit faster.

Comment: because I thought he had the label as the input and not the value of the month. For this I used MonthName.

Comment: @ain There will be no much difference in performance, the biggest problem is that `MONTHNAME` depends on database connection language settings.

Comment: Another big problem of this query is that it can't use an index, because `WHERE` clause is based on functions.

Comment: So you're saying that if for example I had as input the word 'October' to create the two variables should '2011-10-01 'and '2011-10-31' and use the query Mark Byers?

Comment: @JellyBelly Yeah, it's better to convert the input value rather than a column value.